# chosing right confidence interval( left , right , both )

Tags: probability, statistics

I am learning about confidence interval and hypothesis testing.

Lets demonstrate my problem:

The trader says the car burns 8l per 100 miles of fuel. We have to find out if he does or does not lie.

our $H_{0}$ is $\mu=8$ , and $H_{1}$ is $\mu > 8$

So we took 100 cars and calculated average burnout (couldnt find exact word for this ) per 100 miles its our $Xn$

Now we construct RIGHT confidence  interval, using  $(Xn_{\chi_{\alpha}},\inf)$

Where

$\chi_{\alpha} = t_{\alpha,n-1} *\frac{standard deviation}{\sqrt(n)}$

We calcaulate it , checks if 8 is in the interval, if yes we accept hypothesis if not we reject if with $\alpha$ probabilty that its wrong.

However i do not understand, why do we chose RIGHT interval and not left? I fail to find logical decision behind it.

Could someone please explain it to me? If we fin that $Xn$ = 12 , and interval is (9.6 , inf ) We reject hypothesis bcs 8 isnt in the interval. But shoulnt it be good that it does not belong to interval? 
Thanks for answer

Comment: Should your $H_0$ be "fuel consumption is $\mu \leq 8 \text{L}$"?  It would be acceptable for the car to consume less fuel...

Comment: we want to test if he is right, so $H_{0}$ is $\mu=8$ and bad thing is if its higher so $H_{1}$ should be $\mu>8$ atleast thats what was told to me in school

Answer (score 1):

You chose "the trader tells the truth" as your null hypothesis $H_0,$
and "the trader lies" as your alternative hypothesis $H_1.$

If you find that $8$ is outside the confidence interval, you will reject the null hypothesis.
Whether this is a "good thing" or a "bad thing" depends on whether you think it is a "good thing" to find out that the trader is lying.

If you chose a left confidence interval instead of a right confidence interval, then your confidence interval would include all values less than $X_n$ and some values greater than $X_n.$
In particular, if $X_n = 12,$ your confidence interval would include $8$ and you would not be able to reject the null hypothesis--you could not say the trader was lying.
Even if every single trial found that the car burned $2000$ liters in $100$ miles during that trial, you *still* could not reject the null hypothesis,
because $8 < 2000$ and you are using a left confidence interval;
whereas any reasonable person would say it is obvious that the trader lied (and any reasonable statistical analysis would support that statement).

Answer (score 0):

A more accurate characterization of this test is "Test if the trader is *exaggerating* the fuel efficiency". It's assumed you don't care about buying a car with *exactly* 8 liters per 100 miles fuel efficiency, but only that the car is *at least* that efficient (you'd be more than happy if it is actually 4 liters per 100 miles). You are correct that a two-tailed test would be the best one to test if the trader is *inaccurate* (we can't test lying unless you know intent anyway). However, this is not what is actually being tested, so that is a problem with the wording given to you "is trader lying" vs "is trader exaggerating".

The choice of rejection region is not purely mathematical: you need to take into account your *losses* of being wrong. In this case, if the car burns less than 8 liters per 100 miles (i.e., salesperson was being conservative) then you will simply benefit *more* than you expected. So, it makes little sense to spend statistical "power" on testing this situation. You want to focus on the outcome that will produce the most losses -- in this case, getting a car that is not as fuel efficient as advertised.